# Поиск таблиц по записи

Tags: sql

Можно ли найти таблицы по записи?

Например, найти все таблицы, в которых присутствует фамилия *"Петров П.П."* (имя поля также неизвестно).

Или можно, указав имя поля? Допустим, оно во всех неизвестных таблицах одинаковое.

Comment: Какой у вас БД? MySQL, MSSQL, или...?

Comment: _"Петров П.П."_ - это не фамилия.

Comment: MSSQL ....................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

Чистыми средствами SQL - нет.
SQL может производить поиск только в конкретном поле конкретной таблицы.

Один из выходов - указать вручную список всех таблиц и полей для поиска.

Другой выход - каким-нибудь образом построить этот список. Как уже сказал Petr Abdulin, большинство СУБД предоставляют такую информацию, но каждая по своему.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически это возможно. Большинство БД позволяюсь получить метаданные по пользовательским базам (в т.ч. название базы, таблицы в базе, столбы в таблице и т.п.) что в свою очередь позволит вам сконструировать динамические запросы к этим таблицам.

Например чтобы получить имя таблиц в базе `dbName` в БД MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'dbName'
```

то же для MySQL:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName'
```

Comment: Ну так а где мне указать что в искомых таблицах должна присутствовать запись "Петров П.П."?

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо строить сложный запрос. Выбирать во временные таблицы, например, а потом их вязать, синтаксис которого зависит от `СУБД`.

Логика такая:

- выбрать все таблицы пользователя
- в этих таблицах выбрать все столбцы и их типы
- делать поиск по столбцам типа `char/varchar/nvarchar`
- по результатам поиска совершать необходимые действия, которые зависят как от `СУБД`, так и от реализации всего предыдущего процесса